# Expected value of a function of a uniform and a exponential

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

There are three independent r.v.'s $U,X,Y$. $U$ is uniform on $(0,1)$ and $X,Y$ are both exponential of parameter $1$. It can be shown that the ratio $Z=\frac{X}{X+Y}$ has a uniform distribution on $(0,1)$.

I am trying to figure out how to compute the expected value of the function
$$ g(U, X, Y) = \begin{cases} U (1+X) & \text{if } U \ge \dfrac X {X+Y}, \\[10pt]
U(1-X) & \text{if } U < \dfrac X {X+Y}.
\end{cases}$$

The conditional events compare two uniform r.v.'s, but the values of the function depend on $U$ (uniform) and $X$ (exponential).

Comment: Since $U$ and $X/(X+Y)$ are independent and uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$, we have
$$
\Pr\left( U \ge \frac X {X+Y} \right) = \frac 1 2.
$$
Therefore the expected value of the piecewise-defined random variable $g(\cdots)$ is just the ordinary average of the two conditional expected values, given the two complementary events whose probability we just found to be $1/2$. The conditional  joint distribution of $U$ and $X$ given the event $U\ge X/(X+Y)$ would be the next thing to address.  $\qquad$

Comment: Note that $T=g(U,X,Y)$ is $T=U(1-X)+2X\mathbf 1_A$ with $A=[U\geqslant X/(X+Y)]=[Y\geqslant X(1-U)/U]$ and that, for every positive $y$, $P(Y>y)=e^{-y}$, hence $$E(T\mid U,X)=U(1-X)+2XP(A\mid X,U)=U(1-X)+2Xe^{-X(1-U)/U}.$$ Now, $E(1-X)=0$ and, for every positive $x$, $E(Xe^{-xX})=(1+x)^{-2}$, hence $$E(T\mid U)=UE(1-X)+2E(Xe^{-X(1-U)/U}\mid U)=2(1+(1-U)/U)^{-2}=2U^2.$$ Finally, $$E(T)=2E(U^2)=\frac23.$$